# Unauthorised access to Email Settings Google API

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client

I am using both [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM) and the Google API PHP client library to integrate with Google for Work.

I am using a service account and I have authorized the Client ID in the Admin console to access the following two scopes:

1. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
2. `https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/`

I have also enabled the Drive API and Admin SDK in the Developers Console. There is no Email Settings API that I can see.

I have followed [this page](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/Creating-client_secrets.json-and-oauth2service.json) and granted GAM access to all scopes during testing - which does include the Email Settings scope.

I can successfully use GAM and the PHP client library to access the Google Drive API. However, I always get a 403 - Unauthorised when trying to do any of the Email Settings API functions detailed in `https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/`

I am fairly confident that I have the authorised the right Client ID in the Admin Console. When I remove the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` from the Admin Console it blocks my access to Google Drive from both GAM and the PHP client library.

Any suggestions on what to try?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I can show the commands I was executing for GAM since it is much more straightforward. I have removed the identifiers from the output.

> gam oauth info

OAuth File: C:\temp\bin\gam-64\oauth2.txt
Client ID: <client id>
Secret: <secret string of characters>
Scopes:

Comment: Not sure why you'd show GAM since it works. You need to show your code if you expect help identifying the issue.

Comment: GAM does not work either when I try to access the Email Settings API - it only works for the Drive API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAM does not use service accounts for email settings API, it uses standard OAuth 2.0 for installed apps. Be sure you used a super administrator to authorize GAM access to the email settings API. If you didn't, run

```
gam oauth revoke
```

And then another command like:

```
gam all users show imap
```

And this time make sure you are logged in as a super admin.

Answer (score 0):

Jay's post led me to the answer - namely that I should be logged in as a super admin when accessing the Email Settings API.

I therefore created a super admin account and authenticated GAM using that. That gave GAM access.

In order to get the PHP client library working, I had to impersonate the super admin account when I created the OAuth2 token. The code to impersonate the admin account is below:

`$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key,
    'notasecret',                                 // Default P12 password
    'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', // Default grant type
    $admin_email
);`

where

- `$service_account_email` is the email address of the service account created in the Developer's console - not the super admin account.
- `$scopes` is an array of the API URLs that you need to access
- `$private_key` is the contents of the P12 certificate created from the Developer's console.
- `$admin_email` is the email of the super admin account.

Hope this helps someone else.